# Secondary HDD keeps spinning on regular intervals without any obvious reason

Tags: hard-drive

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04. I have it on a SSD drive but I have a secondary non-SSD HDD drive too. I'm not using that drive for anything at the moment yet sometimes it keeps spinning up and for long periods of time. Sometimes these sessions can only be ended by resetting the machine, because it gets unresponsive. Other times I can switch to tty3 for example and then switch back to gui, which makes the spinning cease and the PC works as expacted. Then after a while it may start spinning again, resulting in the same cycle as described before.

It does not happen to often actually, but recently it has started getting on my nerves, because I'm not using that secondary HDD for anything yet there is an exorbitant activity on it.

What can cause this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it formatted and mounted? Try to unmount it.

Comment: I guess it won't be spinning if I unmount it, but it won't give me a reason as to why it keeps spinning.

Comment: How do you know there is activity on it? Do you hear it spinning ? Is is the activity led ? What is on the disk ? What kind of partitions ? swap ? EFI ? anything mounted ? what is in `/etc/fstab`  ?

Comment: It's the led and I can also hear it. It would be fine to get occasional blinks for the reasons you specified but having the file manager open is not a reason to for such an activity that renders my PC pretty much unresponsive.